# Deleting rows depending on two conditions - Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell, conditional-statements

I have a cell-type variable in Matlab alphabetically organized by FIRM.To each FIRM will correspond different and repeated C1s and C2s. For each FIRM I would like to delete repeated C2s (and respective row). The method would be to choose the row whose D2 that's the furthest from D1.

Initial cell:

`FIRMS   C1      C2       D1        D2       D3
'ACRO'  '01464''043605' '19961231''19970212''19970401'
'ACRO'  '01464''043605' '19961231''19970119''19970313'
'ACMJ'  '00118''043605' '19961231''19970114''19970219'
'ACMJ'  '01464''000151' '19961231''19970121''19970218'
'ACMJ'  '00192''007960''19961231''19970523''19970728'`

Final Cell:

`'ACRO' '01464''043605' '19961231''19970212''19970401'
'ACMJ'  '00192''007960''19961231''19970523''19970728'`

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: One possibility is to divide the cell by firm and then I only have to apply the condition of the dates. I will try it like that, it is simple for me, maybe not efficient.

Comment: create a new column with value `abs(D1-D2)` , sort the array based on that column with highest values on lowest row index, then use unique along the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
a = initial_cell;
b = (abs(str2num(cell2mat(a(:,4))) - str2num(cell2mat(a(:,5)))));
[temp ind1] = sort(b);
s  = a(ind1(end:-1:1),:);
[temp1 ind2 temp2] = unique(strcat(s(:,1),s(:, 3)));
out_cell = s(ind2,:);
```

output is

```
out_cell = 

'ACMJ'    '01464'    '000151'    '19961231'    '19970121'    '19970218'
'ACMJ'    '00192'    '007960'    '19961231'    '19970523'    '19970728'
'ACMJ'    '00118'    '043605'    '19961231'    '19970114'    '19970219'
'ACRO'    '01464'    '043605'    '19961231'    '19970119'    '19970313'
```

Note that `out_cell` is sorted by FIRM in this output, while it is not sorted by FIRM in the output stated in the question. Notify me if you need it that way.

Comment: Hey! I was doing the absolute value differently:                                    `a = xx;
b = (abs(cellfun(@minus,a(:,8),a(:,7))));
b=num2cell(b);
a(:,end+1)=b;`                                                            But your way is more concise! Thank you! It worked very well! Just one thing, I took out in your second line the `str2num`, because Matlab was giving me error.(Maybe is just in my code)Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I was verifying the code and despite the fact that it is working, it leaves me with only one `C2`for each firm! And that is not my goal! I want several C2s for each firm, I just don't want them to repeat within themselves! I am sorry I didn't make myself understood! I will work on this topic now!

Comment: @user3557054 Try know, I have changed the answer to choose unique C2 values , earlier it was choosing unique FIRM values,It was my mistake, I didn't read the question properly. Do tell me if there is still some error

Comment: I had already try it similar to what you edited: `[temp1 ind2 temp2] = unique(cell2mat(s(:,3)),'sorted')` but I realized it was wrong too! Because what I want is the two conditions. For example: Firm ACMJ will have 10 different C2 values, but that doesn't mean that one of them will also not appear in firm ACRO. So I cannot sort by C2! I will try with an `&`.

Comment: Ok `&` is obviously not working since one condition is dependent on the other. -.- I will continue my search! :)

Comment: It looks like you need only those rows removed which have both `C2` and `FIRM` values same , Am I right ?

Comment: yes! If I verify that in two (or more) different rows both C2 and FIRM are equal, I will remove one (or more) of them based on the condition of the dates (D1 and D2).

Comment: it doesn't work because I need `cell2mat` for `s(:,3)`so I cannot put them in the `[1 3]` format! They don't have the same data type though they are in the same cell!  :(

Comment: @user3557054 try the edited answer ,I think it is working now,sorry I hadn't checked it earlier

Comment: it worked! Thank you a lot! I did not know this `strcat`function, I am going to check more about in in the internet! Thanks :)